# Access keys inside nested dictionary python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON object like this below. Actually huge JSON file, simplified to ask this question.

```
"header": {
        "headerAttributes": {
            "pageCount": 5,
            "totalCount": 5
        }
    },
"payload": [
    {
        "firstKey": [
                {
                    "nestedKey_1": "1",
                    "nestedKey_2": "2"
                },
                {
                    "nestedKey_3": "3",
                    "nestedKey_4": "4"
                }
            ]
    }
]
```

Now I wrote below python code to access values inside [].

```
Total_Orders_Count = json_response ['header']['headerAttributes']['totalCount']
for i in range(0,Total_Orders_Count): 
            dict = json_response ['payload'][i]
            inner_dict = dict ['firstKey'] [0]
            print inner_dict ['nestedKey_1'] + '(' + inner_dict['nestedKey_2'] + ')'
```

The above code works fine. However, the usage of dict ['firstKey'] [0] doesn't work for values more than 1.

Two Questions.
1. Is there a better way to access Key values inside []. 
2. Can we find length of number of values inside []. For this list, length of values under "firstKey" is 2.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "the usage of dict ['firstKey'] [0] doesn't work for values more than 1" ? what do you mean?

Comment: also don't call your variable `dict`

Comment: `len(json_response['payload'][i]['firstKey'])`

Comment: @barmar Thanks for this to get the length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop over the lists *directly*. There is no need to know a length up front:

```
for d in json_response ['payload']:
    for inner_dict in d['firstKey']:
        print '{0[nestedKey_1]}({0]nestedKey_2})'.format(inner_dict)
```

The `for <name> in <listobject>` loop is a [*for each* construct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop); no indices are generated. Instead, the loop assigns each element from the list to the target name.

I changed the name `dict` to `d` to avoid masking the built-in type. I also used [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to put the values from the inner dictionary into a string.

Note that I dropped using the `totalCount` key altogether. There is no need to look at that value here.

As for finding the length of a list, just use the [`len()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len). Again, there is no need to use that function *here*, iteration directly over the list removes the need to generate indices up front.

Answer (score 0):

In the JSON you provided, there is only one element in the outer list of payload. But the code tries to access the first 5 elements of that list, which don't exist.

Try to avoid using direct access to values in a list like this `di['key']`, instead use 'di.get('key','default')`, unless you are sure it exists.

To loop through the keys-values and get the length of values under 'firstKey', use the following code:

```
for payload in json_response.get('payload',[]) :
    # Length of values under firstKey
    print(len(payload.get('firstKey',[])))
    # To access nested Keys
    for i in payload.get('firstKey',[]) :
        for k,v in i.items() :
            print(k,':',v)
```