# Parsing through Nested Json/dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

dealing with a nasty bit of JSON. I am using json.load to write into a file and have it stored is a dict type , printed below. In python, how would I go about getting a list of just the "dimension" values starting after ""false_value"" (as they first dimension value is not actually a value I want).

I tried kind of a hacky way, but feel like someone may have a perspective on how to do this in a more eloquent fashion.

Goal, make list of all the dimension values (outside the first) such as ( '100', '121' ...)

```
{
    "reports": [
        {
            "columnHeader": {
                "dimensions": [
                    "ga:clientId"
                ],
                "metricHeader": {
                    "metricHeaderEntries": [
                        {
                            "name": "blah",
                            "type": "INTEGER"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "data": {
                "rows": [
                    {
                        "dimensions": [
                            "false_value"
                        ],
                        "metrics": [
                            {
                                "values": [
                                    "2"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
    {
                        "dimensions": [
                            "100"
                        ],
                        "metrics": [
                            {
                                "values": [
                                    "2"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "dimensions": [
                            "121"
                        ],
                        "metrics": [
                            {
                                "values": [
                                    "1"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "dimensions": [
                            "1212"
                        ],
                        "metrics": [
                            {
                                "values": [
                                    "1"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }, ],
                "totals": [
                    {
                        "values": [
                            "10497"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "rowCount": 9028,
                "minimums": [
                    {
                        "values": [
                            "0"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "maximums": [
                    {
                        "values": [
                            "9"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "isDataGolden": true
            },
            "nextPageToken": "1000"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I believe you can iterate through all the keys/subkeys/values and dump them into a list. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45974937

Comment: Did you mean True rather than true (i.e. **True/False** for Python Boolean)?

Comment: @DarrylG this is JSON, not Python code.

Comment: A simple recursive function that uses `isinstance()` in conditions should do the trick.

Comment: @DannyVarod--when OP says "it stored is a dict type , printed below" I assume OP was displaying as a dictionary.  If we consider it as a string, then json.loads(...) gives structural errors (which is also elicited by a json lint validator for the string).  If you change the true to True, then it works as a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should put your json object in a better textual readable form. Use something like [Black](https://black.now.sh/) to clean up the spaces.
Then just transverse the keys till you find your required value, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51788550/parsing-json-nested-dictionary-using-python/51788790) will help you.

You should end up with something like this:

```
dimensions = [row["dimensions"][0] for row in json["reports"][0]["data"]["rows"]]
```

Comment: very cool and neat , ty so much. 

Any tips on how to ignore the first value?

Comment: Check this post: [How to remove the first item in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426663/how-to-remove-the-first-item-from-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

Using recursive function to find values with two conditions

- Parent key was dimensions
- Take only the numeric values

**Code**

```
def find_dims(d, inside = False, results = None):
    '''
        Recursive processing of structure
        inside  = True when parent was "dimensions"
    '''
    if results is None:
        results = []
        
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            find_dims(v, k=="dimensions" or inside, results)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for k in d:
            find_dims(k, inside, results)
    else:
        if inside and d.isdigit():
            # inside dimensions with a number
            results.append(int(d))
            
    return results
```

**Test**

OP Dictinary (changed true to True)

```
d = {
    "reports": [
        {
            "columnHeader": {
                "dimensions": [
                    "ga:clientId"
                ],
                "metricHeader": {
                    "metricHeaderEntries": [
                        {
                            "name": "blah",
                            "type": "INTEGER"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "data": {
                "rows": [
                    {
                        "dimensions": [
                            "false_value"
                        ],
                        "metrics": [
                            {
                                "values": [
                                    "2"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
    {
                        "dimensions": [
                            "100"
                        ],
                        "metrics": [
                            {
                                "values": [
                                    "2"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "dimensions": [
                            "121"
                        ],
                        "metrics": [
                            {
                                "values": [
                                    "1"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "dimensions": [
                            "1212"
                        ],
                        "metrics": [
                            {
                                "values": [
                                    "1"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }, ],
                "totals": [
                    {
                        "values": [
                            "10497"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "rowCount": 9028,
                "minimums": [
                    {
                        "values": [
                            "0"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "maximums": [
                    {
                        "values": [
                            "9"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "isDataGolden": True
            },
            "nextPageToken": "1000"
        }
    ]
}

print(find_dims(d)) # Output: [100, 121, 1212]
```

Answer (score 0):

Like stated in the comments u can just use a simple recursive function, for example:

```
all_dimensions = []
search_key = 'dimensions'
def searchDimensions(data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for (key, sub_data) in data.items():
            if key == search_key: all_dimensions.extend(sub_data)
            else: all_dimensions.extend(searchDimensions(sub_data))

    elif isinstance(data, list):
        for sub_data in data:
            all_dimensions.extend(searchDimensions(sub_data))

    return []

searchDimensions(example)
false_value_index = all_dimensions.index('false_value') + 1
output = all_dimensions[false_value_index:]
print(output)
>>> ['100', '121', '1212']
```

And then filter the values that u don't want (eg. starting from `false_value`)